# Spectrum of operator $T((x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}})=\left(\frac{1}{n^2+1}(x_n-x_{-n})\right)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, spectral-theory, compact-operators

The eigenvalues should satisfy:
$$T(x_n)=\lambda x_n$$
$$\frac{1}{n^2+1}(x_n-x_{-n})=\lambda x_n$$
$$\left[(n^2+1)\lambda+1\right]x_n=x_{-n}$$
I suppose that this should mean that
$$\forall\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\ \exists(x_n)\neq0:T((x_n))=\lambda(x_n)$$
but my teachers solution says the point spectrum is $\{0\}\cup\{\frac{2}{n^2+1};\ n\in\mathbb N \}$.

Where did I go wrong?

**edit**

$T:l^1(\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow l^1(\mathbb{Z})$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $[1-\lambda(n^2+1)]x_n=x_{-n}$?

Comment: What's the domain of the operator $T$? If it's $\ell^2(\mathbb Z)$, you need to ensure that the eigensequence is actually square-summable.

Comment: where you are wrong is that $a_{|n|} x_n = x_{-n}$ for every $n$ not only for $n\ge 0$ !!! so $a_{|n|} x_n = x_{-n}$ AND $a_{|n|} x_{-n} = x_{n}$ i.e. $a_{|n|} = \pm 1$ or $x_n = x_{-n} = 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: if $[1-\lambda(n^2+1)]x_n=x_{-n}$ for all $n$, then $[1-\lambda(n^2+1)]x_{-n}=x_{n}$ for all $n$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence $x=\{ \cdots,0,0,-1,0,1,0,0,\cdots\}$ where the middle $0$ is $x_0$ is mapped to $\{ \cdots,0,0,\frac{-2}{1^2+1^2},0,\frac{2}{1^2+1^2},0,0,\cdots\}$ under the transformation $T$. That is $Tx=\frac{2}{1^2+1^2}x$. In this way you can see that $\frac{2}{1+n^2}$ is an eigenvalue for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$. And $0$ is an eigenvalue also because $Ty=0$ where $y=\{\cdots,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,\cdots\}$.

Let $x_n$ denote the sequence with all $0$'s except for a $-1$ in the $-n$ position, and $1$ in the $+n$ position. And let $y_n$ denote the sequence with all $0$'s except for a $1$ in the $-n$ position and a $1$ in the $n$ position. Then
$$
                Tx_n = \frac{2}{n^2+1} x_n,\;\;\; Ty_n = 0.
$$
You can't have any other point spectrum because the set of all $x_n$ and $y_n$ together form a complete orthogonal basis of $\ell^2$. In fact, if $e_n$ is the standard basis element with $1$ in the $n$-th place and $0$'s elsewhere, then $e_n = \frac{1}{2}(x_n+y_n)$ if $n > 0$ and $e_n = \frac{1}{2}(y_{-n}-x_{-n})$ if $n < 0$. You can use this fact to show that there cannot be any other eigenvalues of $T$.